# Toshiba Satellite A105-S4374 Hard Disk Failing

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

What do I need to get to replace my failing drive on my Toshiba Satellite A105 Laptop (approximately 3 years old)?

Answer (score 3):

The Toshiba support page for the [model A105-S4374](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=SB&os=&category=&moid=1522014&rpn=PSAA8U&modelFilter=A105-S4374&selCategory=3&selFamily=1073768663) claims that the laptop uses a Serial-ATA (SATA) hard disk drive; 9.5mm height.

These are pretty easy to [find](http://arstechnica.shopping.com/xPP-hard_drives--laptop_computer-serial_ata_sata). I think the 9.5mm height drive is the standard size 2.5" wide notebook hard drive.

With regards to taking apart and replacing the HDD, you might try a google search:

- [replace hdd toshiba a105](http://www.google.com/search?q=replace+hdd+toshiba+a105)

The [first result](http://repair4laptop.org/disassembly_toshiba.html) looked promising.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the information.  Do you know of any guides online for how to replace it?  I'm new to this so your input is valuable.  Thanks!